# Organizing My Modal, Cannot add a TH column in Table -Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble organizing my Modal.

Right now it all displays in one big column such as

[image]

I would like the game info to be put into a column, such as

[image]

I need this spread out horizontally as having them stacked on top of each other looks messy since it runs off the screen.

I have tried wrapping them in additional `tr` and `th` tags, but I get an error saying `Element th cannot be nested inside element table`.

Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QPLG7/1/)** that tries to mock the setup. (this does not include the additional wrapper `tr` and `th` tags that I get errors about)

user info includes *name* to *bio*, and game info includes *twitch.tv* to the *required notice*.

Thank you for all the help!

**EDIT**

My attempt in a nutshell

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>
user info
</th>
<th>
game info
</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

All four `th` tags either say they are missing start/end tags, or that it cannot be nested within a `table`.

Comment: Would you wonderful "hit and run" downvote folk, care to explain why this is question sucks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add additional `tables` around my data in order for the compiler to like it.

```
<table>
   <tr>
   <th>
      <table id="userinfo">
      user info
      </table>
  </th>
  <th>
     <table id="gameinfo">
      game info
     </table>
  </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```